# Are the regular sequences of length $n$ one-to-one with the non-decreasing "complete" sequences of positive integers of length $n$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Are the regular sequences of length $n$ one-to-one with the non-decreasing "complete" sequences of positive integers of length $n$?

I confirmed by hand that the number of sequences $(S_i)_{i=1}^n$ with $S_1=1$ and $S_i\leq S_{i+1}\leq1+S_1+S_2+\cdots+S_i$ for all $i\in[1,n)$ equals [$A003513(n)$](http://oeis.org/A003513) for $n=1\ldots5$. Is this true in general? I am far from understanding the definition of a regular sequence, presuming the type referred to in Sloane's A003513 is [this one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_sequence).

Comment: I removed some tags. The "regular sequences" in that Wikipedia article are something completely different.

Comment: @AsalBeagDubh Do you know what the sequences referred to are?

Comment: Do you mean referred to in OEIS? If so, I'm afraid not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears from [this abstract](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0166218X9090066L) that regular sequences in this context are "nondecreasing sequences of positive integers that start with two $1$'s and have the property that each subsequent term is a partial sum of preceding terms."

Clearly each regular sequence corresponds to a "complete" sequence as defined above preceded by a $1$, thus the number of length $n+1$ "complete" sequences is $A003513(n)$.